# How to remove unknown emoji characters from MySQL table

Tags: mysql, emoji

I would like to remove all types of emoji characters from one MySQL column (i.e. bike_store_name). The column values are names of bicycle shops containing many different emoji characters which I want to remove. I just want to keep the actual name of the store and not have emojis. I have over 5K records similar to the ones below. Here's an example of what is found in this table column:

```
 Rent A bicycle Skopelos
 Kairos bicycles
 Beat Bike
 Fitness Equipment Rental Warsaw 
︎ Bicycles Krakow Bicycle Shop
  ️
Hsinchu Angel 999❤️ bike dealership
```

I was able to write a select query to find the emojis, but even with that, I am not 100% sure it is correct. It runs but I am not sure if it's the best way to find all the emojis. Here's the query:

```
SELECT bikeshop_name FROM bsdirectory WHERE HEX(`bikeshop_name`) RLIKE "^(..)*F.";
```

Comment: Please provide a few examples of emojis that it failed to be found.  Provide both the text and the HEX for them.

Answer (score 0):

❤️ is composed of two Emoji, neither of which are caught by that regexp.  (That regexp looks like one I proposed, where did you find it; I should go fix it.)

```
E29DA4    10084=x2764  [❤]   ON  HEAVY BLACK HEART
EFB88F    65039=xFE0F  [️]  NSM  VARIATION SELECTOR-16
```

See if this works:

```
WHERE HEX(bikeshop_name) RLIKE "^(..)*(F.|E2|EF)";
```

If if misses anything, let me know; I will make another crack at the regexp.

The cheat sheet that helped me: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#diagnosing_charset_issues

I see that the regexp may erroneously include some obscure Arabic characters.